# Issue with turkish culture in asp.net

Tags: .net, culture, turkish

We are having an issue related to localization while comparing the strings in the code behind. Below is the scenario.

‘dr’ is a data-row having column name defined in upper case [“NO_OF_CHECKLIST_ITEMS”]
Current Culture = “tr-TR”

Now, it is creating problem while accessing the column using below code when in Turkish culture. It is because in Turkish culture the “i” is different. However, it is working in en-US. 
dr["No_Of_CheckList_Items"]

This will get solved, when used with upper case. But my question is, is there any other efficient way to handle such issues.

Comment: The issue with the Turkish I is well-known, google gives you 98.6 million hits when you query "turkish i problem".  Pretty unclear why you need hit 98,600,001 to get ahead.

Comment: This is a well-known problem.  Please see this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17178605/360840